# RCOH and RCHO Nomenclature

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

In terms of nomenclature, is there a difference between RCHO and RCOH when referring to an aldehyde?

Answer (score 3):

$\ce{RCHO}$ is preferred. The problem with $\ce{RCOH}$ is that it gives the misleading impression that the hydrogen is attached to the oxygen. In fact, I don't believe I've ever seen a reference in literature to an aldehyde using the latter representation.

Answer (score 2):

The [*Graphical Representation Standards for Chemical Structure Diagrams* (IUPAC Recommendations 2008)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277), include recommendations for contracted labels (labels representing more than one non-hydrogen atom) in structure diagrams. In particular

> *GR-2.3.8 Ordering of multiple symbols attached to the same atom*
>   If a single atom is bound to both hydrogen atoms and non-hydrogen atoms, any hydrogen atoms should be presented adjacent to the first atom, followed by the others, reading outward from the bond.

Therefore, a contracted label representing an aldehyde group should be written as $\ce{-CHO}$, since the carbon atom is bound to a hydrogen atom and a non-hydrogen (oxygen) atom, and the hydrogen should be presented adjacent to the first (carbon) atom, followed by the other (oxygen) atom.